# in react i want to select only one user my code is selecting every user

Tags: reactjs, select, button, compiler-errors, mern

im facing issue when i click add friend button every button changes to requested how can i particularly set it to one user only which i clciked i tried few things but it is not working it is selecting every other user. i used handleproductselect function but it is not working i have given them individual id still it is not working

```
class SearchModal extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        Input:"Add Friend",
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        active_id: null,
    }
}

async handleProductSelect(elementid){
  const id = elementid;
  const { backgroundColor } = this.state;
  let newBackgroundColour = backgroundColor === 'white' ? 'yellow' : 'white';
  this.setState({ 
    Input : "Requested",
    backgroundColor: newBackgroundColour,
    active_id: id
  })
  console.log(id)
}

render() {
    const {currentUser} = this.props;
    return (
       <div>
          <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose} 
          >
             <Modal.Header closeButton>
               <Modal.Title>
                 <input 
                  type="text" 
                  placeholder="Search.."
                  value={search}
                  onChange={this.onTextboxChangeSearch}
                 ></input>
               </Modal.Title>
             </Modal.Header>
             <Modal.Body>
               <h3>Users</h3>
               <div>
                <ul className="collection">
                  {userdetails.map((element) => {
                    if(currentUser.user.username !== element.username){
                      return(
                        <div key={element._id}>
                          <li>{element.username}{' '}<input 
                          type="button" 
                          id={element._id} 
                          onClick={this.handleProductSelect.bind(this,element._id )} 
                          value={this.state.Input} 
                          style = {{backgroundColor: ( element._id === this.state.active_id ?  'yellow' : this.state.backgroundColor)}}></input></li>
                        </div>
                      );
                    }else{
                      return(
                        <div key={element._id}>
                          <li>{element.username}</li>
                        </div>
                      );
                    }
                  })}
                </ul>
               </div>
             </Modal.Body>
          </Modal>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You've correctly used state to store the "active id", but you use only a single state to represent the buttons' values.

```
<input 
  type="button" 
  id={element._id} 
  onClick={this.handleProductSelect.bind(this, element._id)} 
  value={this.state.Input} // <-- same single state for all buttons!
  style = {{
    backgroundColor: (element._id === this.state.active_id ?  'yellow' : this.state.backgroundColor)
  }}
/>
```

## Solution

Since I think the intent is to keep the buttons that have been "activated", i.e. you want the label "Requested" to remain, you should add some state to store all the requested active ids. There is also no need to store the static content in state that is the button label, same with background color, this is all derived data based on the `state.active_id` value.

```
this.state = {
  active_id: null,
  requestedIds: {},
}
```

Update `handleProductSelect` to be a curried arrow function. The arrow functions will bind the `this` of the class-component to the callback. The curried function allows you to not need an anonymous callback function just to attach the handler

```
handleProductSelect = id => () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ 
    active_id: prevState.active_id === id ? null : id, // toggle active id
    requestedIds: {
      ...prevState.requestedIds,
      [id]: id, // add requested id
    },
  }));
}
```

Update the `Input` to check if the `requestedIds` has a key for the current element `_id` and conditionally render the button label. Similarly, check the active id for the background color.

```
<input 
  type="button" 
  id={element._id} 
  onClick={this.handleProductSelect(element._id)} 
  value={this.state.requestedIds[element._id] ? 'Requested' : 'Add Friend'}
  style = {{
    backgroundColor: (element._id === this.state.active_id ?  'yellow' : 'white')
  }}
/>
```

Comment: hello @DrewReese im having one trouble in above code what changes i should make to add friendsid in both friendslist like the receiver and user

Comment: @PratikZinjurde I think you may need to provide a little more context around this new question. If you could create a running codesandbox for what you are trying to do I don't mind taking a look when I've some time. This also seems like it is a new question. It may be quicker to post a new SO question though, you'll get more eyes on it. If you do this feel free to (at) me here with a link to it.

Comment: ok thanks but i did this and its working now let user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate( id,{ $push: {"friendsList" : {friendId:fid}} } )
      if (user){
        await User.findByIdAndUpdate( fid,{ $push: {"friendsList" : {friendId:id}} } )// this line i added this and now in both users friendslist each others id is getting added
        res.status(200).json({
          message:"user found",
          user,
        });                                 actually i was asking  how to connect both users like users id is anothers friends id to whom we send request it was like a hack actually

Comment: hello @DrewReese i need ur help when i refresh the value of button resets how to make it permanent im thinking of using localstorage but im not finding where to put that condition of localstorage that if friendsid = userid then it will always show message value of the button

Comment: @PratikZinjurde Sure. A common solution is to use localStorage to persist your app state. You use `componentDidUpdate` to persist component state to local storage, and `componentDidMount` read from and initialize your component state.

Comment: hello @DrewReese i tried this i added this lines inside handleproductselect  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.user);
  localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(currentUser)); its updating localstorage when i logout and again llogin it is not updating at the time i click the add friend button i tried one more thing i get particular userdata by id and updated localstorage with it and it was working properly but it was givving error as the data changed userid is showing undefined.could you help me with tis

Comment: async handleProductSelect(elementid){
  const {currentUser} = this.props;
  const curid = currentUser.user._id ;
  console.log(curid)
  const data = { 
    id: curid,
    fid:fid
   }
  const AddingFriendtoList = await AddFreind(data);
  console.log(AddingFriendtoList);
  const userdata = await UserService.getUser(curid);
  console.log(userdata);
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.user);
  localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(currentUser)); //  not updating as soon as i click  but when i use ocalStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userdata)); this is giving err

Comment: @PratikZinjurde Trying to read code in the comments is very difficult. Do you have this code hosted somewhere it can be viewed? Like in an online sandbox or your repository?

Comment: https://github.com/pratikpz18/Ping/blob/main/frontend/src/components/SearchModal.js this is my github repo you can see above code  but its not hosted yet

Comment: console.log(user.user.friendsList.push({friendId:fid})); i added this line now localstorage is updating instantly but according to mongoose schemma [0]:friendId: "603fa5b48acfb50acc21ddbc"
_id: "603fa5ca8acfb50acc21ddbe",  this is like a hack would you guide me how to keep message value of button activated even after refresh for particular user whose id=friendid in localstorage